# get part of string with php split

Tags: string, query-string, split

i want get part of value from a database
i know i must use split code but its going to remove from php
so i must use what now
for example i have

```
<html>
<header>
<body>
<?php
$value = "10-20-30-40-50-87";
//i want to get 30 for example
?>
```

i know i can use

```
$aryStr = split("#", $string); 
 print "$aryStr[0]<br>";
 print "$aryStr[1]";
```

but its give me a error in php5.3
so what i must use now for get 40 from value

Comment: This is off the top of my head, but shouldn't it be: `$aryStr = split("-", $value);`

Comment: yes i know i just give a example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [PHP explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function to split the $value into an array of Strings.

```
$value = "10-20-30-40-50-87";
$pieces = explode("-", $value);
echo $pieces[0]; // 10
echo $pieces[1]; // 20
```

Comment: so fast and So usable and that Why Im So love you :D thank you